# Create and call a simple web service in ASP.Net using REST and XML

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web

I am new at programming and am trying to find a resource that can tell me how to create a simple web service where I can read data from an XML file I have, using .Net and REST. Most of the resources I've found talk about WCF or SOAP.I will not be using data from a database or SOAP or using WCF to create this Web Service. I am using an empty ASP.NET Web Application.

Comment: Well something like [Microsoft own resources for ASP.Net](https://www.asp.net/web-api) should work...Hth

Comment: Thanks @EdSF this is exactly what I needed